# When to drop list Comprehension and the Pythonic way?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, pylint, code-complete

I created a line that appends an object to a list in the following manner

```
>>> foo = list()
>>> def sum(a, b):
...      c = a+b; return c
...
>>> bar_list = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
>>> [foo.append(sum(i,x)) for i, x in enumerate(bar_list)]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> foo
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
>>>
```

The line

```
[foo.append(sum(i,x)) for i, x in enumerate(bar_list)]
```

would give a pylint W1060 Expression is assigned to nothing, but since I am already using the foo list to append the values I don't need to assing the List Comprehension line to something.

**My questions is more of a matter of programming correctness**

Should I drop list comprehension and just use a simple for expression?

```
>>> for i, x in enumerate(bar_list):
...      foo.append(sum(i,x))
```

or is there a correct way to use both list comprehension an assign to nothing?

**Answer**

Thank you @user2387370, @kindall and @Martijn Pieters. For the rest of the comments I use append because I'm not using a list(), I'm not using i+x because this is just a simplified example.

I left it as the following:

```
histogramsCtr = hist_impl.HistogramsContainer()
for index, tupl in enumerate(local_ranges_per_histogram_list):
    histogramsCtr.append(doSubHistogramData(index, tupl))
return histogramsCtr
```

Comment: I realize this is just an example, but why append at all? Why not just `foo = [sum(i, x) ...]`?

Comment: `sum(i, x)` doesn't work. Do you mean `i + x`?

Comment: If you really want a 1-liner, you can put a `for` loop on one line. Not recommended, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is bad style. A list comprehension is to build a list. You're building a list full of `None`s and then throwing it away. Your actual desired result is a side effect of this effort.

Why not define `foo` using the list comprehension in the first place?

```
foo = [sum(i,x) for i, x in enumerate(bar_list)]
```

If it is not to be a list but some other container class, as you mentioned in a comment on another answer, write that class to accept an iterable in its constructor (or, if it's not your code, subclass it to do so), then pass it a generator expression:

```
foo = MyContainer(sum(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(bar_list))
```

If `foo` already has some value and you wish to append new items:

```
foo.extend(sum(i,x) for i, x in enumerate(bar_list))
```

If you *really* want to use `append()` and don't want to use a `for` loop for some reason then you *can* use this construction; the generator expression will at least avoid wasting memory and CPU cycles on a list you don't want:

```
any(foo.append(sum(i, x)) for i, x in enumerate(bar_list))
```

But this is a good deal less clear than a regular `for` loop, and there's still some extra work being done: `any` is testing the return value of `foo.append()` on each iteration. You can write a function to consume the iterator and eliminate that check; the fastest way uses a zero-length `collections.deque`:

```
from collections import deque
do = deque([], maxlen=0).extend

do(foo.append(sum(i, x)) for i, x in enumerate(bar_list))
```

This is actually fairly readable, but I believe it's not actually any faster than `any()` and requires an extra import. However, either `do()` or `any()` is a little faster than a `for` loop, if that is a concern.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's generally frowned upon to use list comprehensions just for side-effects, so I would say a for loop is better in this case.

But in any case, couldn't you just do `foo = [sum(i,x) for i, x in enumerate(bar_list)]`?

Comment: I can't since in my program foo is a container object, the append method does some other things.

Comment: Then either just use a for loop, or, if the container object is of a class you defined, maybe change the `__init__` to use *args so you can do `foo = MyContainerFoo(sum(i,x) for i, x in enumerate(bar_list))`

Comment: That doesn't require the use of `*args`. The generator expression is one argument.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I would prefer to define it so it can be initialized as either `MyClass(1,2,3,4,5)` (using *args) or `MyClass(*(i for i in range(1,6)))`, rather than `MyClass([1,2,3,4,5])` or `MyClass(i for i in range(1,6)`, but thats just me.

Answer (score 3):

You should **definitely** drop the list comprehension. End of.

- You are confusing anyone reading your code. You are building a list for the side-effects.
- You are paying CPU cycles and memory for building a list you are discarding again.

In your simplified case, you are overlooking the fact you could have used a list comprehension directly:

```
[sum(i,x) for i, x in enumerate(bar_list)]
```